# Excel: How to prune duplicates and combine their values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Say I have a simple two column table

```
value-a | 3
value-b | 7
value-b | 2
value-c | 5
```

i want the output to be

```
value-a | 3
value-b | 9
value-c | 5
```

Thanks

PS. I'm hoping this is just a really simple function. I attempted to use 'consolidate' but failed miserably. I'm not too familiar with Excel scripting or how to even run it.

Comment: would a pivot table suffice as a solution?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not even really sure what that is :/

Comment: try [this](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-create-pivot-table-excel)

Comment: Thank you, that is a great tutorial.

Comment: Consolidate works beautifully; you should learn it. Seriously! VBA is much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of besides the tutorial link provided by Jaycal.

## Non VBA Solution

Select entire `Column A` » right-click » `Copy` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Select cell `C1` » right-click » Paste As Values

Select the entire `Column C` » go to `Data Tab` » Remove Duplicates

[image]

Once you click the `Remove Duplicates` on the next pop-up `Continue with the current selection` and make sure you only selected `Column C`

This will remove duplicates. Now all you need is to stick a formula in cell `D1`

`=SUMIF(A:A,C1,B:B)`

grab the right-bottom corner of the cell and drag it down til the last cell in `Column C`

This will solve your problem without VBA

[image]

## VBA Solution

```
Sub RemoveDupsAndSumUp()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Columns("A:A").Copy
    Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("$C:$C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-3],RC[-1],C[-2])"
    Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth considering Subtotal:

[image: SO18903348 example]